# Why there's only one-way ping between two routers?

Tags: routing

I have a ZTE F609 connected to ISP with local address 192.168.1.1/23. I also have a Tenda 11N connected to the ZTE. The Tenda WAN address is 192.168.1.97/23 and local address 192.168.2.1/24

My problem is that from Tenda I could access ZTE's LAN at 192.168.1.x, while from ZTE I couldn't access the Tenda's LAN at 192.168.2.x

What could be the problem/s?

The ZTE routing table:

```
Network Address    Subnet Mask      Gateway         Interface
0.0.0.0            0.0.0.0          180.242.32.1    omci_ipv4_pppoe_1
10.0.0.165         255.255.255.255  10.13.137.1     omci_ipv4_dhcp_2
10.8.0.0           255.255.255.0    192.168.1.89    LAN
10.13.137.0        255.255.255.0                    omci_ipv4_dhcp_2
180.242.32.1       255.255.255.255                  omci_ipv4_pppoe_1
192.168.0.0        255.255.254.0                    LAN
```

I tried adding `192.168.2.0 255.255.254.0 192.168.1.97 LAN` route to the ZTE but every ping request to 192.168.2.x were still timed out.

The Tenda routing table:

```
Destination IP  Subnet mask   Gateway       Hops    Interface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0       192.168.1.1   1       vlan2
192.168.0.0     255.255.254.0 192.168.0.0   0       vlan2
192.168.2.0     255.255.255.0 192.168.2.0   0       br0
```

Every ping request to any of 192.168.0.x from Tenda were replied.

[The ZTE routing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl4PE.png) and [The Tenda routing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEwo1.png)

Comment: You don't have a routing problem.  Likely there is some filter or firewall feature that blocks ping requests coming from the WAN interface of the Tenda.

Comment: I got every firewall related settings in the both the ZTE and Tenda router disabled, but still no access to Tenda's LAN. From ZTE I can ping Tenda WAN IP (192.168.1.97) but not its local IP (192.168.2.1). I guess I should try to get another router to see if the Tenda really was the culprit.

Comment: I tried replaced Tenda with a TP-Link MR3420. Now the ZTE 192.168.1.0 subnet could reach TP-Link 192.168.3.0 subnet. But only if I turned off Bandwidth Control feature on the TP-Link router! What gives?!

Comment: And now it stopped working again.